# How to filter whole dashboard data, based on the authenticated user region

Tags: laravel, filter, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

i'm facing this problem where i must show only data related to the region that the current user belongs to, but if you're let's say the global manager of the solution you could see all of the data.
i'll give an example let's say my solution is working in Paris and Berlin, the users in Paris would see data related to paris only (orders, total of the orders etc) but the full owner of the app sees both Berlin and Paris data combined, note that it is not based on role but rather on hierarchy because i didn't fix roles in the app so you could create any role you want and attach the permissions for it and select it's hierarchy level.
i tried to use global scopes in the app so that i could prefilter the models based on the region, the issue is that it doesn't work with query builders (and i've a lot) and that i've to go and check for each query and insert it manually which will be a lot and might break the app.
if you've any suggestions on how i should be able to deal with this problem be my guest, it's been months and i'm desperate for help honestly.

I tried to put global scopes on every model, like the model "Employees" so that the authenticated user based on his hierarchy level, would see the "employees" below his level, but the problem with the approach is that it works with Eloquent only.

Comment: "I tried to put global scopes on every model, ... but the problem with the approach is that it works with Eloquent only" - what else does it need to work with?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.